# Is it possible to find the value of a polynomial from the generating function?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

Suppose I've to find $H_4(0),$ where $H$ represents the Hermite polynomial. I've only been provided with the following relation :

$$e^{-t^2+2tx}=\sum_n H_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}$$

My first step is to substitute $x=0$ in the above relation, to get :

$$e^{-t^2}=\sum_n H_n(0)\frac{t^n}{n!}$$

Expanding the exponential in the form of a Taylor series, we get :

$$\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{n!}=\sum_n H_n(0)\frac{t^n}{n!}$$

However, I'm unable to proceed from here. Similarly, in legendre polynomial, I'm stuck, and I'm unable to proceed any further. In some problems regarding Euler polynomial however, this method seems to work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If two power series are equal, then the coefficients of each power must be equal.  You have a mistake, the right hand side of your equality involving the expansion of $e^{-t^2}$ should contain $H_n(0)$ not $H_n(x)$

Comment: Taking the derivatives of both sides and putting $t=0$ you get
$$H_n(x)=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial t^n}e^{-t^2+2tx}\,\Big|_{t=0}$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav thank you so much, that works ! However, is there a special reason for substituting $t=0$ in the end ?

Comment: @NickCastillo thank you so much, that was a typing error from my end.

Comment: Yes, because you have to drop all other terms in the Taylor series with the powers higher than $n$. $\,\,t=0$ in the end is mandatory :)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Perhaps you should make that an answer!

Comment: Basically, it directly follows from the definition of the generating function: $e^{-t^2+2tx}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty H_k(x)\frac{t^k}{k!}$. Taking $n$ derivatives over $t$ you get $\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial t^n}e^{-t^2+2tx}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty H_k(x)\frac{t^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}$. Imposing the condition $t=0$ you leave only one term - $H_n(x)$ - on the RHS